# What browsers are supported by Formance.js

Tags: jquery-plugins, cross-browser

On what browsers will the jQuery Formance.js library work, and on what browsers will it not work.

https://github.com/omarshammas/jquery.formance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given it's a jQuery library, the compatibility should be the same as [jQuery itself](http://jquery.com/browser-support/). The [Getting Started](https://github.com/omarshammas/jquery.formance/wiki/Getting-Started) example refers to jQuery 1.8.3, which supports:

- IE 6+
- the 2 most recent stable versions of Chrome
- the 2 most recent stable versions of Firefox
- Safari 5.1+
- the 2 most recent stable versions of Opera, and 12.1x
- iOS 6.0+
- Android 4.0+